# Mocha - limit the number of asynchronous 'it' calls executing simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, mocha.js

I am running a test under the Mocha framework, which executes a lot of test cases:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    it(`test case ${i}`, async function() {
        let x = await func(...);
        assert(something about x);
    });
}
```

`func` is an `async` function which communicates with a remote process via HTTP.

Soon thereafter, test cases begin to fail, and I believe that this is because the system cannot issue anymore asynchronous HTTP requests.

Since `it` is implemented in the Mocha framework itself, I have no control on how it is executed.

Is there any way to configure Mocha to limit the number of `it` calls executed simultaneously?

Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: The tests are run one after another, they are not run in parallel [look](https://realguess.net/2015/04/01/test-execution-order-in-mocha/)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT: The `it`s - yes, the functions that they execute in this case - no, because each one is an `async function` (look in the code).

Comment: To me you are going to create 1.000.000 of `it` which are returning `Promise` objects which is supported natively by Mocha. Mocha will so, execute every `it` one after another. That's what I think. You can insert `console.log` before and after the `func` execution, so you will see if mocha does wait or does run every `it` asynchronously

Comment: Are you sure `let x = await func(...);` is behaving correctly always? as in returning a promise always that is correctly waiting before being resolved...

Answer (score 0):

**Mocha** will first register all the **1000000** test cases. Then it will execute them one by one.
 So even if the **functions** that  **`it`s** execute are **`async`**, **Mocha** will run the next test **only** after the previous testcase. So **`it`** calls are **not** executing simultaneously.

Therefore problem really is with the line:
 `let x = await func(...);` 
So may be **`func`** is not behaving as it should for which the tests are failing.